# Existence of a classical solution to some linear parabolic PDE with Dirichlet condition

Tags: differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider the following parabolic PDE (Fokker-Planck equation) for $u: \mathbb R_+\times\mathbb R_+ \to\mathbb R$:

$$\partial_t u(t,x) = \frac{1}{2(1+q(t))}\partial^2_{xx}\big(a(t,x)u(t,x)\big)-\frac{1}{1+q(t)}\partial_{x}\big((b(t,x)+c(t))u(t,x)\big),\quad \forall t,x>0$$

and $u(0,\cdot)=f$ and $u(\cdot,0)=0$, where $b, a: \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R_+$ are functions as nice as possible (bounded, of bounded derivatives of any order and $\inf_{(t,x)}a(t,x)\ge 1$), $f:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ is smooth, integrable and $f(0)=0$. Assuming that $q, c: \mathbb R_+\to [0,1]$ are $1/6-$Holder continuous and $q$ is decreasing, can we show the existence of a classical solution to the above problem?

I am looking for a reference and any answer and comments are appreciated.